# Avoid tooltip grabbing mouse focus

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

How can I spawn a tooltip close to my cursor without the OnMouseExit handler being called. Is there any way to make the tooltip opaque to mouse focus?

A JIRA issue was created several years ago describing a similar situation: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8118199 .

---

Working with a canvas I attached mouse listener to continuously show a tooltip and update accordingly to the data drawn beneath it.

```
    Tooltip tt = new Tooltip();
    tt.setAnchorLocation(AnchorLocation.CONTENT_BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tt.setAutoFix(false);

    double offset = 100;

    this.setOnMouseMoved((event) -> {

        //Position tooltip
        if (!tt.isShowing()) {
            tt.show(this, event.getScreenX() - offset, event.getScreenY() - offset);
        } else {
            tt.setX(event.getScreenX() - offset);
            tt.setY(event.getScreenY() - offset);
        }

        //Update text
        int xBucket = (int) ((event.getX() - marginLeft - gridXOffset) / (gridWidth / xSections));
        int yBucket = (int) ((event.getY() - marginTop) / (gridHeight / ySections));
        DoubleSummaryStatistics stat = dat[xBucket][yBucket];
        tt.setText("Occurances: " + stat.getCount() + "\n"
                + "Average Fitness: " + df.format(stat.getAverage()) + "\n"
                + "Max Fitness: "  + df.format(stat.getMax()) + "\n"
                + "Min Fitness: "  + df.format(stat.getMin()));
    });

    this.setOnMouseExited((event) -> {
        if (tt.isShowing()) {
            tt.hide();
        }
    });
```

As you can see the tooltip is displayed a little bit to the top left due to the defined offset. If the value is set two  a smaller value (20-0) the tooltip will grab the focus as soon as it is displayed and the setOnMouseExit handler will be immediately called resulting in a flickering loop.

[image]

Comment: That bug report also links to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092020.

Comment: @VGR I have seen this, but it was created years ago and hasn't been worked on since. This is the reason why I am ´looking for a workaround